# TideSDK apps on Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspberry-pi

I am looking to build an app that runs on a Raspberry Pi in full screen mode. I have already tried JavaFX and  swing based app and the performance is really bad.

Before I jump on to SDL(http://www.libsdl.org/) i want to check and see if anyone has successfully build apps using the TideSDK on the PI.

Appreciate your insights on the challenges

Answer (score 0):

You have to give chance to **Qt**
    [ http://wiki.qt.io/Main ]